# How does auto regression work with correlated independent variables?

Tags: time-series, regression, forecasting, arima

I know that auto-regression is a regression with lag variables. But, we know that in linear regression, we cannot use correlated independent variables. 
Then how does auto-regression work? And what is the difference between that and linear regression?

Comment: Are you more interested in how auto-regressive (AR) model -- that is the specific time series method works -- or how you handle collinear variables if you included "lagged" variables?

Comment: Am interested in the second part of it